# Is it safe to use one server fd in multiple epoll event loops in different threads?

Tags: linux, sockets, io

I have one server fd, and several threads with epoll event loop in each of them (different epoll_fd's). Is it safe, if I would add this fd to every event loop? Is it true, that only one of them would be notified if a new client arises?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it safe, if I would add this fd to every event loop?

It is safe insofar that `epoll` will not crash and will not complain about it. If your code can handle it properly is unknown.

> Is it true, that only one of them would be notified if a new client arises?

I would not count on this. It is more likely that all threads get notified but only one will then be able to handle the event - the others might just block on `accept` (unless the socket is set non-blocking).